# Validations Groups doesn't working with forms

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

I'm trying to setup groups validation on my symfony project.
When I update an entity, I only need to validate some fields. When I create an entity, I only need to validate some other fields.

Service:

```
$form = $this->formFactory->createNamed('form', FormType::class, $entity, ['validation_groups' => ['update']]);
```

Form:

```
class FormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('user', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => User::class,
                'validation_groups' => ['create']
            ])
            ->add('number', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Numbers::class,
                'validation_groups' => ['create', 'update']
            ])
            ->add('phone', TextType::class, [
                'validation_groups' => ['create', 'update']
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Phones::class,
            'allow_extra_fields' => true,
            'validation_groups' => ['create', 'update'],
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ]);
    }
}
```

But, when I submit my form, the "user" field still validated.

```
{"form":{"user":748,"number":"9.2","phone":"0x xx xx xx xx"}}

{"id":957,"error":"Expected argument of type \"App\\Entity\\User\", \"null\" given at property path \"user\"."}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specifify `validation_groups` on fields.
Groups passed into form options are applied to all fields by default.

```php
# Service 1
// Only 'create' group will be validated
$this->formFactory->createNamed('form', FormType::class, $entity, ['validation_groups' => ['create']]);

# Service 2
// Only 'create' and 'update' group will be validated
$this->formFactory->createNamed('form', FormType::class, $entity, ['validation_groups' => ['create', 'update']]);

# Form
class FormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('user', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => User::class,
                // 'validation_groups' => ['create']
            ])
            ->add('number', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Numbers::class,
                // 'validation_groups' => ['create', 'update']
            ])
            ->add('phone', TextType::class, [
                // 'validation_groups' => ['create', 'update']
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Phones::class,
            'allow_extra_fields' => true,
            // 'validation_groups' => ['create', 'update'],
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ]);
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't seem like form validation error (violation).
`Expected argument of type \"App\\Entity\\User\", \"null\" given at property path \"user\"` means, that value passed into 'user' field is null (not set).
You should omit 'user' field when it form is used for 'creation'.

#### Solution 1:

```php
// add option 
$resolver->setDefaults([
    'data_class' => Phones::class,
    // ...
    'addUserField' => null,
]);

// in service pass this option
$this->formFactory->createNamed('form', FormType::class, $entity, [
   'validation_groups' => ['create'],
   'addUserField' => true
]);

// use condition in form to add field only if option is passed with true value
if($options['addUserField'] === true) {
    $builder->add('user', EntityType::class, [class' => User::class]);
}
$builder
   ->add('number'/** ... */)
   ->add('phone'/** ... */)
;
```

#### Solution 2:

Create 2 form types `FormTypeCreate` and `FormTypeUpdate`. Skip 'user' field in `FormTypeUpdate`. You could also extend `FormTypeCreate` from `FormTypeUpdate`.

```php
class FormTypeUpdate extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('number', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Numbers::class,
            ])
            ->add('phone', TextType::class)
        ;
    }
    //...
}

//
class FormTypeCreate extends FormTypeUpdate
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('user', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => User::class,
        ])
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options); // adds 'number' and 'phone' fields
    }
    //...
}
```